# PHP MySQL select * WHERE id = > 100

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a blog with English and Swedish posts. I first wrote in English and then switched to Swedish.

My question is, If there is any way to only display post with a higher id?

Like:

```
select * FROM blog WHERE id is bigger than 100
```

Anyone get my drift and know if this is possible? :)

I don't want to delete the old posts, and I also don't want people to see them.

Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id > 100` ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use SELECT * FROM blog WHERE ID > 100 ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

```
   Select *
    From blog
    Where Id > 100
    Order by ID DESC
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html for more information.
If the ID is auto-incremented, this will bring the newest articles first, and not display the one with ID smaller than 100.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Try this

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id > 100
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! An so easy too :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though all the answers seem correct, it looks to me you actually want to have just the last 20 or so blog posts. In that case use LIMIT.

```
select * from blog order by id desc limit 20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a system for showing posts, you might rather want to show the latest few posts, which can be done with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT '100';
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Select query have syntax for bigger then is > you can do

select * FROM blog WHERE id > 100

Hope above will help.